# Linebreaks in PHP mail(): \n, \\n and \r\n dont work

Tags: php

This is on a LAMP server.

All the answers I've found online suggest that one of the above should work, but I cant get it working.

My code is:

```
$to      =  $email_to;
$subject = 'Website Form';
$message = 'From: ' . $name . 

' \r\n Date: ' .  $date . 

' \r\nText: ' .  $text . 

'\r\n Use on Presentations?: ' . $presentations . 

'\r\n Use on Websites?: ' . $website . 

'\r\n Use on Case Studies?: ' . $casestudy;

$headers = 'From: website@website.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: no-reply@website.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Would anyone know what I've done wrong?

Comment: not working for headers or message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using single quotes, if you want to use \n or \r you have to put them in double quotes, like:

```
$value = "here is some text, and a $variable, and a line end\r\n";
```

I do a lot of php mailer stuff and \r\n has to be in "..." or it's not executed as an escaped character, but rather as a literal.

Ie:

```
echo ".\n.";
# is this:
.
.
#but
echo '.\n'.;
#is this:
.\n.
```

that's all.

Answer (score 0):

For that you can set header like `$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";` and then user `<br />` in place of `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `\r\n`, use `<BR>`

```
$message = 'From: ' . $name . 

' <BR> Date: ' .  $date . 

' <BR>Text: ' .  $text . 

' <BR>Use on Presentations?: ' . $presentations . 

' <BR>Use on Websites?: ' . $website . 

' <BR>Use on Case Studies?: ' . $casestudy;
```